# Utilising extra memory on SD card

Tags: sd-card, openelec

On system info of OPENELEC i can see that 6,9Gb space is available  /dev/mmcblk0p2.
I don't know how to refer to this space either from PC or MAC or from within openelec. I am sure it is a stupid user question and apologize for it but I just cant find an answer.

Comment: OpenELEC has **[this](http://kodi.wiki/view/File_manager)** doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

if you go onto raspi-config via (`sudo raspi-config`) on LX terminal, you should have an option to expand filesystem storage. Select that and expand it to your desired size.

PS: I don't use OpenELEC, I use Raspbian. It should be the same anyway (or not?)

Answer (score 1):

This is mounted as /storage in the filesystem. All smb shares you see when connecting from the pc via \\openelec are on this partition, and all configuration data, as well as the default media paths are there. The rest of the filesystem is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

In Raspbian, if you enter the command `raspi-config`, there is an option to expand the file system. I believe it is the first option on the main menu.

If you are using noobs, it should have already expanded to utilize the extra space unless you made an extra partition on the noobs startup screen.

Comment: R.S.Lord states that he's using OpenElec.